# Gravar variável customizada no Banco CDR do SNEP

Tags: asterisk

Tenho um servidor `snep` e pelo `dial-plan` eu fiz uma solicitação na URA onde o cliente que ligou precisa digitar sua carteirinha.

Fiz as validações se a carteirinha existe no banco do cliente pelo odbc direto no dial plan e ele valida normalmente e só permite a continuação da ligação apos a carteirinha existir.

O que preciso fazer, e que não acho como, é passar esta variável da carteirinha para a parte responsável em gravar as ligações na tabela `CDR` para um campo customizado "`carteirinha`" que eu criei nesta mesma tabela.

Comment: Olá. Qual a versão do SNEP instalada? Qual a versão asterisk utilizada na sua instalação do SNEP?

Answer (score 1):

Será necessário configurar o banco de dados e o asterisk versão 1.8 ou superior conforme os seguintes passos (testado na versão 11):

- adicionar o campo "carteirinha" na tabela 'cdr' do banco de dados;
- Setar o campo 'carteirinha' no plano de discagem do asterisk por meio da função CDR(), conforme exemplo a seguir;
- recarregar o plano de discagem e modulo cdr_mysql, ou reiniciar o asterisk.

Exemplo:

```
exten => s,1,...
exten => s,n,Read(numeroDaCarteirinha)
exten => s,n,Set(CDR(carteirinha)=${numeroDaCarteirinha})
... etc etc
```

OBS: Testado com asterisk 11, mysql 5.4 e rodando no Centos7

Comment: vou tentar muito obrigado

Comment: Excelente. Favor dar um Upvote se a resposta se mostrar útil.

Comment: Deu certo? Se sim, favor marcar a resposta como uma solução válida.

Comment: nao consegui afzer ainda estou fazendo alguns testes. eu fiz da forma q vc passou mas ele nao grava no banco. ja tentei ate setar algo fixo como exten => s,n,Set(CDR(carteirinha)='0001') mas nao grava no campo da tabela